# Angular *ngFor to repeat buttons with list items

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I am building a web App using **Angular 2** and want to loop the button with the list items but outside of list items, how can I get the functionality using ***ngFor**, please help.

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
            <a class="list-group-item clearfix" style="background-color:rgb(3, 0, 48)" *ngFor="let buying of buy">
                <div class="pull-left" style="max-width:350px">
                    <h5 style="color:white">{{buying.names}}</h5>
                    <p style="color:white">{{buying.desc}}</p>
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="pull-right" >
                        <img [src]="buying.getImg" alt="image not loaded" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:100px">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-6"> <-----I WANT TO LOOP THIS BUTTON
                <button class="btn btn-primary ; pull-right">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you please share some expected output with an example list

Comment: `buy` is object or array can you check ..?

Comment: @chiragsorathiya it is an array.

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR i want to make like this (  https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simple-To-Do-List-App-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-3.jpg  )

Comment: I think provided answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet. I have created a div tag above linking both content and then added the loop inside that, so it will refer to both elements (item and button).

```html
<div *ngFor="let buying of buy">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a class="list-group-item clearfix" style="background-color:rgb(3, 0, 48)">
      <div class="pull-left" style="max-width:350px">
        <h5 style="color:white">{{buying.names}}</h5>
        <p style="color:white">{{buying.desc}}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="pull-right">
          <img [src]="buying.getImg" alt="image not loaded" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:100px">
        </span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary ; pull-right">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```